# Disabling Server-Side Rendering using Angular 2 Webpack starter

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, .net-core

When disabling server-side rendering using the Angular 2 Webpack starter (using the Visual Studio Asp.Net Core Template Pack - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack) I get a blank page with the error:

Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (http://localhost:39581/dist/vendor.js?v=uDhibyj1JCvnQ_atjbkYgdDXemO3YhimVE71Ib9XzU4:13837:52)

I have updated my packages to the latest as per latest version generated using "yo-generator aspnetcore spa"

In my Index.cshtml page I have replaced the following:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

with

```
<app></app>
```

Am i missing a step somewhere, any reference I can find to disabling server-side rendering only mentions removing the asp-prerender-module tag.

Snapshot of my package.json as follows:

```
@angular/common": "2.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.2",
"@angular/core": "2.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.2",
"@angular/http": "2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.2",
"@angular/router": "3.0.2",
"@types/jQuery": "2.0.34",
"@types/node": "^6.0.42",
"@types/react": "0.0.0",
"angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.11",
"angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
"angular2-universal": "~2.0.11",
"angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.11",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
"aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17"
```